# Create an array which cumulatively iterates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am building a model that will take a gas tank, cumulatively remove the daily usage, and then record the number of resupplies required over a time period (dictated by a trigger, which activates when it drops below a specific level).

I am however tying myself up in for loops and I am sure there is an easier way to do it.

The problem I am having is (if I use the example below rather than the code) is: I can't  take the usage from the tank cumulatively, but in a way that allows it to return back to full capacity when it hits the resupply trigger.

I have tried using np.cumsum, but when it resupplies at <6 it would then remove 5 not 1.

example of what I want to achieve:

```
tank = 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 10

usage = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 

resupply = 2
```

This is my current code attempt:

```
f_resupply_trigger = 6000
f_tank_volume = 10000
f_tank_current = np.full((91,1),f_tank_volume)
f_resupplies = 0

#Calculate the daily usage rate per type
f_flow_o = f_plan_v * flow_rate[0]
f_flow_o2p = f_plan_v * flow_rate[1]
f_flow_v = f_plan_v * flow_rate[2]
f_flow_CV = np.array([f_flow_o + f_flow_o2p + f_plan_v])
f_flow_total_CV = np.cumsum(f_flow_CV, dtype=float)

#calcualate what is in the tank by taking the daily consumption from the tank
for i in f_flow_total_CV:
    for y in f_tank_current:
        a = y - i
        y = a
        y = y+1
    i = i + 1

# predict the resupply requirement
for i in f_tank_current:
    if i < f_resupply_trigger:
        f_tank_current = f_tank_volume
        f_resupplies + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: You should say exactly what your question/problem is...

Comment: Thank you - sorry it wasn't clear, I have updated, I hope it is clearer now.